# Adding Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, math, variables

So, I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I was wondering how I would add the values from two inputs and echo out the result. Here's what I have so far:

```
function math (form) {
    var input1 = form.input1.value;
    var input2 = form.input2.value;
    var input3 = input1 + input2;
    document.write (input3);
}
```

```xml
<form action="" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="input1">
   <input type="text" name="input2">
   <input type="button" name="button" onClick="math(this.form)">
</form>
```

I expected that when I entered a number into each input it would spit out the sum of the two numbers. Instead it just prints both numbers individually.

How can I get it to print the sum of the two numbers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.value` gives the characters in the textbox, i.e. a string. You somehow need to tell JavaScript that it's a number. Otherwise you're concatenating the strings (`str + str` is concatenating; `num + num` is adding arithmetically).

String to number conversion is most easily done with `+` like this:

```
+input1
```

So in your case:

```
document.write(+input1 + +input2);
```

However, `document.write` is not the way to display things. You probably want `alert`, or put it in another textbox or something like that. `document.write` will clear the screen.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I was just using document.write temporarily until I got some other stuff sorted out.

Answer (score 12):

They are strings when you read them in, they must be parsed first,

```
var input3 = parseInt(input1, 10) + parseInt(input2, 10);
```

**[Edit]** Just to elaborate, the difference between `parseInt` and the Unary Plus is in the error handling,

```
var a = parseInt('123o45', 10); //123
var b = +'123o45' // NaN
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between `parseInt` and Unary Plus.

Answer (score 3):

parseInt is your firend here..

```
function math (form) {
  var input1 = form.input1.value;
  var input2 = form.input2.value;
  var input3 = parseInt(input1, 10) + parseInt(input2, 10);
  document.write (input3);
}
```

Comment: ParseInt without specifying the radix is generally a bad idea. Should be `parseInt(input1, 10)` to make sure it parses all strings as decimal.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to parse them to integers first using parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked well with parsing them to `Float` as I am having decimal digits. Instead of `parseInt()`, I used `parseFloat()`.

I hope it'll help somebody in future.